# What are the model, current ram size and max ram size supported by this laptop?

Tags: laptop, hardware, ram

I boot into a live Lubuntu usb on the laptop, and run `lshw` see below.  (Please help me remove private info in the output, if I miss to do so. I have only removed serial numbers. Anything else I miss to remove?)

Is it correct that it currently has 4GB RAM?

What is the maximum RAM that the laptop can support?

- Is the model of the laptop "C55Dt-A (PSCFWU)"? Following that, I found at 
  https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Toshiba/satellite-c55dt-a-(pscfwu-03p005) which says "Maximum Memory: 8GB".
- If I search "C55Dt-A" instead, I found max 16GB RAM support at https://www.cnet.com/products/toshiba-satellite-c55dt-a5305-15-6-a6-5200-4-gb-ram-750-gb-hdd-us/ and https://support.toshiba.com/supportmodel/PSCFWU-02000D (https://support.toshiba.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=4004241&isFromTOCLink=false)

What is the correct max ram supported by the laptop? What is the model of the laptop? Thanks.

```
$ sudo lshw

lubuntu
    description: Notebook
    product: Satellite C55Dt-A (PSCFWU)
    vendor: TOSHIBA
    version: PSCFWU-00X005
    serial:  
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Durban Curiosity 10AN sku=PSCFWU uuid=CD932420-D25D-11E2-B47A-008CFA609299
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Portable PC
       vendor: TOSHIBA
       physical id: 0
       version: MP
       serial: 1
       slot: Base Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.80
          date: 01/27/2014
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 4032KiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int9keyboard int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics
          serial: NotSupport
          slot: Socket FT1
          size: 874MHz
          capacity: 1500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc hw_pstate proc_feedback vmmcall bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: d
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: M471B5673FH0-CF8
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial:  
             slot: DIMM 0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: M471B5773CHS-CK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 
             slot: DIMM 1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Kabini [Radeon HD 8330]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
             resources: irq:35 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f2000000-f27fffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f2900000-f293ffff memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:37 memory:f2940000-f2943fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f1000000-f1ffffff ioport:f0000000(size=16777216)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: enp1s0
                version: 07
                serial: 
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:32 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f1000000-f1000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f2800000-f28fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                logical name: wlp5s0
                version: 01
                serial: 
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.95 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:40 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f2800000-f2803fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB XHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 10
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f2948000-f2949fff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage pm msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:33 ioport:4118(size=8) ioport:4124(size=4) ioport:4110(size=8) ioport:4120(size=4) ioport:4100(size=16) memory:f294e000-f294e3ff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f294d000-f294dfff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 12.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:f294c000-f294c0ff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f294b000-f294bfff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:f294a000-f294a0ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: FCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 3a
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: latency=0
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: FCH Azalia Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:38 memory:f2944000-f2947fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: FCH LPC Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=fam15h_power
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
             vendor: Toshiba
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 3M
             serial: 
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=b3b8c372-58cc-4b4f-8586-b1ccd8d87fc4 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 1022MiB
                capacity: 1023MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-05-02 21:30:19 filesystem=ntfs label=System modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: FAT32
                serial: 
                size: 255MiB
                capacity: 259MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=Basic data partition
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 122MiB
                capacity: 127MiB
                capabilities: nofs precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-05-02 21:30:23 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                logical name: /media/lubuntu/TI10664800G
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 226GiB
                capacity: 226GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-05-02 21:30:26 filesystem=ntfs label=TI10664800G mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 name=Basic data partition state=mounted
           *-volume:4
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 325MiB
                capacity: 349MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-11-05 08:04:12 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:5
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                logical name: /media/lubuntu/New Volume
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 226GiB
                capacity: 226GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-08-25 01:12:31 filesystem=ntfs label=New Volume modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:6
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 7
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,7
                logical name: /dev/sda7
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 11GiB
                capacity: 11GiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-06-15 07:37:53 filesystem=ntfs label=Recovery name=Basic data partition state=clean
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: CDDVDW SU-208DB
             vendor: TSSTcorp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: TF01
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 3
          bus info: usb@5:1
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: UDisk
             vendor: General
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             logical name: /cdrom
             version: 5.00
             size: 3840MiB (4026MB)
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: ansiversion=2 logicalsectorsize=512 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 sectorsize=512 state=mounted
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
                logical name: /cdrom
                size: 3840MiB (4026MB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 signature=67e97428 state=mounted
              *-volume
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: /dev/sdb2
                   version: FAT12
                   serial: 
                   size: 15EiB
                   capabilities: primary boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
```

Comment: You can use `sudo lshw -sanitize` when you want to share `lshw` output without sensitive information

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on what you posted, it looks like:

1. You have 4GB of memory.
2. You have a Satellite C55Dt-A (PSCFWU)
3. So your laptop can take up to 16GB of memory.

But that's based on what you posted.  I would personally trust lshw, but you can get a definitive answer even if you don't.

Find the serial number on the bottom of your laptop and type it into https://support.toshiba.com/ . I'm sure it will tell you what model you have.

Comment: Thanks. https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Toshiba/satellite-c55dt-a-(pscfwu-03p005) says max 8GB RAM, so is it wrong?

Comment: Do I miss to remove any private information? Or are all the serial numbers the only private information that I need to remove?