# How could I find out the requirements on RAMs that can work with a laptop?

Tags: laptop, ram, motherboard

I have a laptop (Model Name:     SATELLITE C55DT-A5244), and want to find a 16GB RAM to replace the 4GB RAM in it.

How could I find out from Lubuntu 18.04 the requirements on the specifications of RAMs that can work with the laptop?  Does the output of `lshw` below suffice?

What specifications must a new RAM   meet? Capacity, [frequency](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130621/why-do-free-and-lshwshow-different-ram-sizes), latency, and more?

Thanks.

```
$ sudo lshw

lubuntu
    description: Notebook
    product: Satellite C55Dt-A (PSCFWU)
    vendor: TOSHIBA
    version: PSCFWU-00X005
    serial:  
    width: 64 bits
    capabilities: smbios-2.7 dmi-2.7 smp vsyscall32
    configuration: boot=normal chassis=notebook family=Durban Curiosity 10AN sku=PSCFWU uuid=CD932420-D25D-11E2-B47A-008CFA609299
  *-core
       description: Motherboard
       product: Portable PC
       vendor: TOSHIBA
       physical id: 0
       version: MP
       serial: 1
       slot: Base Board Chassis Location
     *-firmware
          description: BIOS
          vendor: Insyde Corp.
          physical id: 0
          version: 1.80
          date: 01/27/2014
          size: 128KiB
          capacity: 4032KiB
          capabilities: pci pnp upgrade shadowing cdboot bootselect edd int9keyboard int10video acpi usb agp smartbattery biosbootspecification netboot uefi
     *-cpu
          description: CPU
          product: AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD]
          physical id: 4
          bus info: cpu@0
          version: AMD A4-5000 APU with Radeon(TM) HD Graphics
          serial: NotSupport
          slot: Socket FT1
          size: 874MHz
          capacity: 1500MHz
          width: 64 bits
          clock: 100MHz
          capabilities: x86-64 fpu fpu_exception wp vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush mmx fxsr sse sse2 ht syscall nx mmxext fxsr_opt pdpe1gb rdtscp constant_tsc rep_good nopl nonstop_tsc cpuid extd_apicid aperfmperf pni pclmulqdq monitor ssse3 cx16 sse4_1 sse4_2 movbe popcnt aes xsave avx f16c lahf_lm cmp_legacy svm extapic cr8_legacy abm sse4a misalignsse 3dnowprefetch osvw ibs skinit wdt topoext perfctr_nb bpext perfctr_llc hw_pstate proc_feedback vmmcall bmi1 xsaveopt arat npt lbrv svm_lock nrip_save tsc_scale flushbyasid decodeassists pausefilter pfthreshold overflow_recov cpufreq
          configuration: cores=4 enabledcores=4 threads=4
        *-cache:0
             description: L1 cache
             physical id: 8
             slot: L1 Cache
             size: 256KiB
             capacity: 256KiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=1
        *-cache:1
             description: L2 cache
             physical id: 9
             slot: L2 Cache
             size: 2MiB
             capacity: 2MiB
             clock: 1GHz (1.0ns)
             capabilities: pipeline-burst internal write-back unified
             configuration: level=2
     *-memory
          description: System Memory
          physical id: d
          slot: System board or motherboard
          size: 4GiB
        *-bank:0
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
             product: M471B5673FH0-CF8
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 0
             serial:  
             slot: DIMM 0
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
        *-bank:1
             description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
             product: M471B5773CHS-CK0
             vendor: Samsung
             physical id: 1
             serial: 
             slot: DIMM 1
             size: 2GiB
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
     *-pci:0
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Root Complex
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 100
          bus info: pci@0000:00:00.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
        *-display
             description: VGA compatible controller
             product: Kabini [Radeon HD 8330]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.0
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
             configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
             resources: irq:35 memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f2000000-f27fffff ioport:4000(size=256) memory:f2900000-f293ffff memory:c0000-dffff
        *-multimedia:0
             description: Audio device
             product: Kabini HDMI/DP Audio
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
             physical id: 1.1
             bus info: pci@0000:00:01.1
             version: 00
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm pciexpress msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=0
             resources: irq:37 memory:f2940000-f2943fff
        *-pci:0
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.2
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:24 ioport:3000(size=4096) memory:f1000000-f1ffffff ioport:f0000000(size=16777216)
           *-network
                description: Ethernet interface
                product: RTL8101/2/6E PCI Express Fast/Gigabit Ethernet controller
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                logical name: enp1s0
                version: 07
                serial: 
                size: 10Mbit/s
                capacity: 100Mbit/s
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd autonegotiation
                configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=half firmware=rtl8106e-1_0.0.1 06/29/12 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII speed=10Mbit/s
                resources: irq:32 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:f1000000-f1000fff memory:f0000000-f0003fff
        *-pci:1
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Family 16h Processor Functions 5:1
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 2.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:02.3
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pm pciexpress msi ht normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:25 ioport:2000(size=4096) memory:f2800000-f28fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter
                vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:05:00.0
                logical name: wlp5s0
                version: 01
                serial: 
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rtl8188ee driverversion=4.15.0-20-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.95 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
                resources: irq:40 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:f2800000-f2803fff
        *-usb:0
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB XHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 10
             bus info: pci@0000:00:10.0
             version: 01
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress xhci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=xhci_hcd latency=0
             resources: irq:18 memory:f2948000-f2949fff
        *-storage
             description: SATA controller
             product: FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode]
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 11
             bus info: pci@0000:00:11.0
             version: 00
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: storage pm msi ahci_1.0 bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ahci latency=64
             resources: irq:33 ioport:4118(size=8) ioport:4124(size=4) ioport:4110(size=8) ioport:4120(size=4) ioport:4100(size=16) memory:f294e000-f294e3ff
        *-usb:1
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 12
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.0
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f294d000-f294dfff
        *-usb:2
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 12.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:12.2
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:f294c000-f294c0ff
        *-usb:3
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB OHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 13
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.0
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: ohci bus_master
             configuration: driver=ohci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:18 memory:f294b000-f294bfff
        *-usb:4
             description: USB controller
             product: FCH USB EHCI Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 13.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:13.2
             version: 39
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: pm debug ehci bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=ehci-pci latency=32
             resources: irq:17 memory:f294a000-f294a0ff
        *-serial UNCLAIMED
             description: SMBus
             product: FCH SMBus Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.0
             version: 3a
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             configuration: latency=0
        *-multimedia:1
             description: Audio device
             product: FCH Azalia Controller
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.2
             version: 02
             width: 64 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=snd_hda_intel latency=32
             resources: irq:38 memory:f2944000-f2947fff
        *-isa
             description: ISA bridge
             product: FCH LPC Bridge
             vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
             physical id: 14.3
             bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
             version: 11
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 66MHz
             capabilities: isa bus_master
             configuration: latency=0
     *-pci:1
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 101
          bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:2
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 0
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 102
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.0
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:3
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 1
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 103
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.1
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:4
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 2
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 104
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.2
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-pci:5
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 3
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 105
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.3
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=k10temp
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:6
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 4
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 106
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.4
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
          configuration: driver=fam15h_power
          resources: irq:0
     *-pci:7
          description: Host bridge
          product: Family 16h Processor Function 5
          vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
          physical id: 107
          bus info: pci@0000:00:18.5
          version: 00
          width: 32 bits
          clock: 33MHz
     *-scsi:0
          physical id: 1
          logical name: scsi0
          capabilities: emulated
        *-disk
             description: ATA Disk
             product: TOSHIBA MQ01ABF0
             vendor: Toshiba
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sda
             version: 3M
             serial: 
             size: 465GiB (500GB)
             capabilities: gpt-1.00 partitioned partitioned:gpt
             configuration: ansiversion=5 guid=b3b8c372-58cc-4b4f-8586-b1ccd8d87fc4 logicalsectorsize=512 sectorsize=512
           *-volume:0
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 1
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,1
                logical name: /dev/sda1
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 1022MiB
                capacity: 1023MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-05-02 21:30:19 filesystem=ntfs label=System modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:1
                description: Windows FAT volume
                vendor: MSDOS5.0
                physical id: 2
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,2
                logical name: /dev/sda2
                version: FAT32
                serial: 
                size: 255MiB
                capacity: 259MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount fat initialized
                configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat name=Basic data partition
           *-volume:2
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 3
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,3
                logical name: /dev/sda3
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 122MiB
                capacity: 127MiB
                capabilities: nofs precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-05-02 21:30:23 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:3
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 4
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,4
                logical name: /dev/sda4
                logical name: /media/lubuntu/TI10664800G
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 226GiB
                capacity: 226GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-05-02 21:30:26 filesystem=ntfs label=TI10664800G mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 name=Basic data partition state=mounted
           *-volume:4
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 5
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,5
                logical name: /dev/sda5
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 325MiB
                capacity: 349MiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-11-05 08:04:12 filesystem=ntfs modified_by_chkdsk=true mounted_on_nt4=true resize_log_file=true state=dirty upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:5
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 6
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,6
                logical name: /dev/sda6
                logical name: /media/lubuntu/New Volume
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 226GiB
                capacity: 226GiB
                capabilities: ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-08-25 01:12:31 filesystem=ntfs label=New Volume modified_by_chkdsk=true mount.fstype=fuseblk mount.options=rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0,default_permissions,allow_other,blksize=4096 mounted_on_nt4=true name=Basic data partition resize_log_file=true state=mounted upgrade_on_mount=true
           *-volume:6
                description: Windows NTFS volume
                vendor: Windows
                physical id: 7
                bus info: scsi@0:0.0.0,7
                logical name: /dev/sda7
                version: 3.1
                serial: 
                size: 11GiB
                capacity: 11GiB
                capabilities: boot precious readonly hidden nomount ntfs initialized
                configuration: clustersize=4096 created=2013-06-15 07:37:53 filesystem=ntfs label=Recovery name=Basic data partition state=clean
     *-scsi:1
          physical id: 2
          logical name: scsi1
          capabilities: emulated
        *-cdrom
             description: DVD-RAM writer
             product: CDDVDW SU-208DB
             vendor: TSSTcorp
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@1:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/cdrom
             logical name: /dev/cdrw
             logical name: /dev/dvd
             logical name: /dev/dvdrw
             logical name: /dev/sr0
             version: TF01
             capabilities: removable audio cd-r cd-rw dvd dvd-r dvd-ram
             configuration: ansiversion=5 status=nodisc
     *-scsi:2
          physical id: 3
          bus info: usb@5:1
          logical name: scsi2
          capabilities: emulated scsi-host
          configuration: driver=usb-storage
        *-disk
             description: SCSI Disk
             product: UDisk
             vendor: General
             physical id: 0.0.0
             bus info: scsi@2:0.0.0
             logical name: /dev/sdb
             logical name: /cdrom
             version: 5.00
             size: 3840MiB (4026MB)
             capabilities: removable
             configuration: ansiversion=2 logicalsectorsize=512 mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 sectorsize=512 state=mounted
           *-medium
                physical id: 0
                logical name: /dev/sdb
                logical name: /cdrom
                size: 3840MiB (4026MB)
                capabilities: partitioned partitioned:dos
                configuration: mount.fstype=iso9660 mount.options=ro,noatime,nojoliet,check=s,map=n,blocksize=2048 signature=67e97428 state=mounted
              *-volume
                   description: Windows FAT volume
                   vendor: mkfs.fat
                   physical id: 2
                   logical name: /dev/sdb2
                   version: FAT12
                   serial: 
                   size: 15EiB
                   capabilities: primary boot fat initialized
                   configuration: FATs=2 filesystem=fat
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/91868/discussion-on-question-by-tim-how-could-i-find-out-the-requirements-on-rams-that).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the model, current ram size and max ram size supported by this laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118684/what-are-the-model-current-ram-size-and-max-ram-size-supported-by-this-laptop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments...

The RAM specs, and pricing for available upgrades can be found at:

https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Toshiba/satellite-c55dt-a5244

It's about $100 to get two 8G RAM sticks.

Detailed Toshiba specs are at:

https://support.toshiba.com/support/staticContentDetail?contentId=4001583&isFromTOCLink=false

Comment: Thanks. The products at crucial.com are too expensive to me. I am in a very tight budget. It also lists the products, instead of telling me what kinds of RAM that can work with my laptop. I would like to know the specification requirements on RAM that can work with my laptop, so that I can look for less expensive options else where

Comment: @Tim as I mentioned before... read the answers that you're given. Go to the second link for the **exact** specs that you're asking for. And, if your budget is tight, and $100 is too much right now, then you're done shopping.

Comment: The RAM you need for your laptop is shown as type **DDR3** (209 pins) at 1333 MHz. A lot of DDR3 RAM sold today runs at 1600 MHz. You can buy at that speed too, but it won't run at that speed, because your laptop isn't built for that frequency.

Comment: @PaulBenson Thanks. (1) Is  1333MHz the min freq of RAM for my laptop? Any higher frequency will work for my laptop? (2) When looking for a RAM for a laptop, do I need to look at something else than capacity, frequency, pin number, and mechanism (DDRx)?

Comment: (3) Do I need to stick to DDR3? Do higher or lower DDRx's work too?

Comment: 1333MHz is **maximum** for your laptop. The RAM you have currently shown  in your output are much less than that frequency. DDR3 is not compatible with any other RAM type as they have different pin numbers so you must stick to that.

Comment: @PaulBenson THanks. (1) Maximum or minimum? "It means that your computer was designed to run with memory that runs at a minimum of 1.3 GHz - faster memory will be OK - slower memory can cause system problems. See https://superuser.com/questions/715901/what-happens-if-i-ins‌​tall-slower-ram-than‌​-specified-compatibl‌​e-with-the-motherbo" see https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49764706#49764706  (2) does 209 pins mean form factor, and  DDR3 means something else?

Comment: You must use DDR3. Any other number won't fit in the slots. 1333MHz is the max. Buy 1600 and it will run at 1333. Buy 800MHz and RAM will then run at that speed. Buy 2 modules,  800 and 600 and it will run at 600.