# Why do free and lshw show different RAM sizes?

Tags: ram, free, lshw

1. In Lubuntu 18.04 in a laptop (Model Name:     SATELLITE
   C55DT-A5244), `free` shows its RAM ram is 3.3G

   ```
   $ free -h
                 total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
   Mem:           3.3G        1.2G        444M         46M        1.7G        1.8G
   ```

   while `lshw` shows the RAM should be 4GiB

   ```
    *-memory
         description: System Memory
         physical id: d
         slot: System board or motherboard
         size: 4GiB
       *-bank:0
            description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 533 MHz (1.9 ns)
            product: M471B5673FH0-CF8
            vendor: Samsung
            physical id: 0
            serial:  
            slot: DIMM 0
            size: 2GiB
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 533MHz (1.9ns)
       *-bank:1
            description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous Unbuffered (Unregistered) 800 MHz (1.2 ns)
            product: M471B5773CHS-CK0
            vendor: Samsung
            physical id: 1
            serial: 
            slot: DIMM 1
            size: 2GiB
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 800MHz (1.2ns)
   ```

   Why do the 3.3G and 4GiB differ? The difference between 4GiB i.e.
   4.29497 GB, and   3.3G  is 0.99GB, i.e. 990MB.

   The two RAM chips have **different frequencies**: 533MHz and 800MHz. Can
   that be a problem? What frequencies should the two RAM chips be?
2. In another Thinkpad T400 laptop, under Lubuntu 18.04, `free` and
   `lshw` also don't report the same RAM size, though with  difference 
   smaller than the previous laptop: `free` shows 7.7G RAM, and `lshw`
   shows 8GiB RAM from two RAM chips of **the same frequency**.  The
   difference between 8GiB i.e. 8.58993 GB, and   7.7G  is 0.89GB, i.e.
   890MB.

   ```
    *-memory
         description: System Memory
         physical id: 2b
         slot: System board or motherboard
         size: 8GiB
       *-bank:0
            description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
            product: SUPERTALENT02
            vendor: 8634
            physical id: 0
            serial: 00000000
            slot: DIMM 1
            size: 4GiB
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
       *-bank:1
            description: SODIMM DDR3 Synchronous 1066 MHz (0.9 ns)
            product: SUPERTALENT02
            vendor: 8634
            physical id: 1
            serial: 00000000
            slot: DIMM 2
            size: 4GiB
            width: 64 bits
            clock: 1066MHz (0.9ns)
   ```

Thanks.

Comment: You are comparing GB with GiB. The one is decimal, the other binary. Plus your graphics card probably gets a bit of RAM. Use `free --gibi`.

Comment: Thanks. How can I find out the amount of system RAM that's shared to the built-in graphics adapter?

Comment: This is the THIRD time that you've asked about memory here. Listen closely to the answers you've received before. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130619/how-could-i-find-out-the-requirements-on-rams-that-can-work-with-a-laptop and https://askubuntu.com/questions/1118684/what-are-the-model-current-ram-size-and-max-ram-size-supported-by-this-laptop?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How could I find out the requirements on RAMs that can work with a laptop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1130619/how-could-i-find-out-the-requirements-on-rams-that-can-work-with-a-laptop)

Comment: @heynnema Are the questions about RAM the same? Can I beg you please bother to read and understand what the questions are about, before blindly accusing dupliates? Please be friendly, respectful, inclusive, accepting. Much apprecated. I am in a very bad situation, and feel I am dying when I have to argue over these kinds of things.

Comment: You've asked similar questions since Feb 2019. Are you **really** looking to expand your RAM? Get the **correct** model # from the tag that's on the bottom of your laptop (not lshw), then go to crucial.com.

Comment: @hey I am, but I am in very tight budget and a very bad situation, which explains why I hesitate.

Comment: https://www.crucial.com/usa/en/compatible-upgrade-for/Toshiba/satellite-c55dt-a5244

Answer (score 5):

In both cases, the difference is probably the amount of system RAM that's shared to the built-in graphics adapter.  There is also some amount of RAM taken by the OS that doesn't show (it's usually a small amount, and varies depending on a number of factors, including kernel version and compiled-in drivers).  This RAM isn't shown by *free* because it's not available for the OS to use at any time, but *lshw* is examining the hardware information, not the BIOS/OS reported RAM figures.

Comment: The rest of the difference is the difference between power of 1000 and 1024. Use  `free -h --si` for `* 1024`

Comment: Thanks. How can I find out the amount of system RAM that's shared to the built-in graphics adapter?

Comment: Generally, subtraction will do the job.  With modern chipsets, it'll be a multiple of 128 MB.  Usually this is user configurable in BIOS setup, so looking there for what it's set at is a good check.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Do you mean the amount of system RAM that's shared to the built-in graphics adapter? Can I find it out without restarting my Lubuntu?

Comment: Given that graphics are generally the only thing that will take away from system RAM, getting the two figures in the same units (GB or GiB) and subtracting one from the other will give the result.  Other than that, I don't offhand know a way to explicitly display the graphics RAM amount (though I'm pretty sure there is one).

Comment: Thanks. Both two laptops run 64-bit Lubuntu 18.04 and the differences are not " 256 MB or 384 MB" as in your reply: (1) In the first laptop:  `lshw` shows 4GiB i.e. 4.29497 GB, and `free` shows 3.3G. Their difference is 0.99GB, i.e. 990MB.  (2) In the second laptop:  `lshw` shows 8GiB i.e. 8.58993 GB, and `free` shows 7.7G. Their difference is 0.89GB, i.e. 890MB.

Comment: Is that machine running 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu?  32-bit without the HWE layer will only "see" 3.5 GiB max.

Comment: Which reports "the BIOS/OS reported RAM figures", `free` or `lshw`?